# Make a Google Cloud signed url public

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to search through the documentations and I think I found a solution but it isn't working and I continue to get an error. What I am doing for a signedUrl is

```
  const [url] = await googleCloud
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .file(filename)
    .makePublic()
    .getSignedUrl(options);

  return { url };
```

What I added from what I found in the docs was `makePublic()` but this throws and error as it is followed by `getSignedUrl`. I don't have any problem if I remove `makePublic()` and upload the file from the signed url but the file won't be public.

Any advice on how I should proceed?

**UPDATE**

The error I am seeing when trying to get a signed url with `makePublic` is `[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: googleCloud.bucket(...).file(...).makePublic(...).getSignedUrl is not a function]`.

Additional information in regards to the options being send with `getSignedUrl` function are

```
  const options = {
    version: 'v4',
    action: 'write',
    expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
    contentType: 'video/quicktime',
  };
```

**UPDATE (How frontend handles signed url)**

```
  const submitReview = async () => {
    const url = await getSignedUrl({
      variables: { filename: "google3.mov" }
    }).then(async response => {
      if (response.data && response.data.getSignedUrl) {
        const url = response.data.getSignedUrl.url;
        const pathUrl = url.split('?');
        const videoPath = pathUrl[0];
        
        const uploadedReponse = await uploadToGoogleCloud(url);
      }
    });
  }
  
  const uploadToGoogleCloud = async (url) => {
    const videoFile = await fetch(video.uri);
    const blob = await videoFile.blob();

    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: blob
    }).then(res => console.log("thres is ", res)).catch(e => console.log(e));
  }
```

Comment: Why are trying to create a SignedUrl for a public object? Note: SignedUrl requires a config object. Edit your question with more context and the exact error message.

Comment: I am trying to use a signedUrl in order to upload content from the client side (not the backend since it is a lot slower going from frontend -> my backend -> cloud then back). The reason why I want to make it public is so the content can be viewed by those viewing posts. I have added some additional information. Please let me know if you need more info and thank you for the help.

Comment: Where is the source file? Where is the destination? If they are both in Google Cloud Storage, then you need to use a bucket object copy operation. Otherwise you will need to read the object and then write the object. The function `getSignedUrl` creates and HTTP url. In your example, you are pipelining methods together which will not accomplish your goal.

Comment: @JohnHanley I have updated to show the frontend portion on how I'm using fetch and the URL to send the video. The way it is done currently is, I request a signedUrl in order to perform an upload, fetch the video by the local url given after a person selects a video, convert that into a blob then send it to Google Cloud Storage. All this works except not public. Sorry If I didn't understand what was mentioned in your previous reply.

Comment: Update your question and remove confusing parts. Show the current state of the code and errors. Do not mix `makePublic` and `getSignedUrl` in the same method chain, use one or the other.

Comment: Please follow John Hanlye suggestion. You should use either makepublic or getSignedUrl, not both.

Answer (score 0):

It took me forever to find good information on this, so I'm adding an answer here to hopefully help someone else.

You can have a writable signedUrl be set to be publicly available on a one off basis by requiring and setting the `x-goog-acl` header to `public-read`. This assumes your Google Cloud bucket is set to use Access Control Lists (ACLs) rather than the default [Uniform bucket-level access](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access). See more about setting object ACLs [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/put-object-acls).

Typescript Example:

```
public async getPublicUploadURL(bucketName: string, filename: string, filetype: string): Promise<string> {
    const file = await this._cloudStorage.bucket(bucketName).file(filename);

    const response = await file.getSignedUrl({
        version: "v4",
        action: "write",
        expires: Date.now() + 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
        contentType: filetype,
        extensionHeaders: {
            'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'
        }
    });

    return response[0];
}
```

This function will return a signedUrl that can be uploaded to, and *must* include the `x-goog-acl: public-read` header. If it isn't included in the `extensionHeaders` in the signedUrl configuration object, then it *can't* be included as a header when uploading the file.

As an example, you could upload a file to that signedUrl using `axios` and it would be publicly available.

```
const uploadFile = async (file: File, signedUrl: string) => {
    const headerObj = {
        'Content-Type': file.type,
        'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'
    }

    await axios.put(signedUrl, file, { headers: headerObj });
};
```